# Correct way to add liquibase to an existing spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, database-migration, liquibase

I have an existing spring boot project and a database for the same. Now, I would like to add liquibase to handle further database migration. What are the correct steps to do this?

I have followed [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app) to add liquibase and generate changelog. Most articles I've found talk about using liquibase in a project starting from scratch or are not too detailed about the implementation. So far, I've done the following:

Added the dependencies and plugin in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    //..other dependencies
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Added the liquibase.properties file under src/main/resources

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb
username=root
password=root
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
outputChangeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml
```

Updated the application.properties file under src/main/resources to handle changelogs

```
#Hibernate
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demodb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

#Jpa
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

#Liquibase
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

Created the `db.changelog-master.xml` file under src/main/resources/db/changelog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd">

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Ran the spring boot app so that two new tables are created in the database - `DATABASECHANGELOG` (which is empty at the moment) and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` (which has a single null entry at the moment)

Generated the `demodb-changelog.xml` file from the terminal to create the changelog for the current state of the database

```
mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog
```

Then to sync the current changelogs as executed, in `liquibase.properties` added:

```
changeLogFile=src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml
```

And then from the terminal ran:

```
mvn liquibase:changelogSync
```

Now, the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table has entries for the changelogs as executed.

Next in the `db.changelog-master.xml` file, added the generated file:

```
<include file="db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml"/>
```

Now, when I run the app, I get the exception:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: 
Migration failed for change set db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'abc' already exists
```

So, this is trying to run the changelog files again. How do I configure to run only those changesets that have not yet been run? I thought that the function of the `DATABASECHANGELOG` was to handle the changesets that have been executed, but I guess I'm wrong here.

I could run the application without the `include` tag in `db.changelog-master.xml`, but I guess all the changelog files need to be listed here as I would need all the changelog files if I were to run this app in a different machine to create the entire database from scratch.

So how to configure liquibase to run only changelogs that have not yet been executed?

Comment: did you try including the generated file in changelog-master and then running changeLogSync?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is `filename` field stored in the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table.

Liquibase determines identity of the `changeSet` not just by `id` or by `id` and `author`, but instead it determines identity of the `changeSet` based on value of **all three fields:** `id`, `author`, `filename`.

When you run `mvn liquibase:update` or `mvn liquibase:changelogSync`, the `filename` of your changelog is `src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml`. This is value that stored by liquibase into `DATABASECHANGELOG.FILENAME` field in each table row.

But, when you start your spring-boot application, the filename of your changelog is `classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`, and filename of included into it changelog is `db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml`.

Then, Liquibase checks what changesets are already applied.

It checks the `id`, `author` and `filename` of each changeset from `DATABASECHANGELOG` table and each changeset in the `db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml` file, and it found that nothing matched, because `filename` field differs. In the DB it's value is `src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml`.

```
src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml != db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml
```

So, Liquibase thinks these are different changesets and tries to apply them. It fails because table already exist. But if you change your changesets to something that can be applied multiple times, you will see that Liqibase created a new set for rows in the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table with same `id`, same `author` but different `filename`...

Honestly, I don't know how to solve this problem. It looks like a fundamental problem of how Liquibase in Spring Boot works. When changelog files are read on spring-boot application start, they **MUST** be in classpath, especially if default fat-jar used. But when you run Liquibase as maven plugin, <s>they are usually on local file system</s> (it's not true, see my "Update 2").

Maybe some workaround exist, please add it in comment and I'll update the answer.

**Update**

One workaround that I found is to use `logicalFilePath` attribute of [`<databaseChangeLog>`](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog.html) tag.

> Use to override the file name and path when creating the unique identifier of change sets. Required when moving or renaming change logs.

If you carefully set it in all your changelogs/changesets, it should work.

An example for your `db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd"
        logicalFilePath="db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml">

</databaseChangeLog>
```

But take care of `<include>` tag. It supports including of raw `*.sql` files. And you can't set `logicalFilePath` for them. And `logicalFilePath` that is set on `<databaseChangeLog>` tag is also not inherited.

**Update 2**

I found a more robust solution.

Just don't specify the prefix `src/main/resources` in `changeLogFile` property of maven plugin. This way maven will search changelog in classpath, not in filesystem. So, you must do `mvn process-resources` first, before executing liquibase maven plugin.

So, your `changeLogFile` property of liquibase maven plugin (`liquibase.properties` file) should look like this:

```
changeLogFile=db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml
```

Then, when you run

```
mvn process-resources liquibase:changelogSync
```

Liquibase will create records in `DATABASECHANGELOG` table with `FILENAME` field equal to `db/changelog/changes/demodb-changelog.xml`, which is equal to filename, used by spring-boot when it runs migrations on startup (`classpath:` prefix automatically stripped by Liquibase when it compares filenames). And finally this makes Liquibase to understand, that these are the same set of changesets, and they are already applied.

Comment: Your solution in Update 2 works, and is what I have in a test project I'm playing around with. There is one interesting quirk, however. Just having liquibase-core in your Spring Boot Project causes liquibase to run on your changelog automatically during the mvn process-resources phase, without outputting any logs indicating that it is doing so.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL will maintain the log for liquibase in table,

Liquibase uses the DATABASECHANGELOG table to track which changeSets have been ran.

Whenever the changelog runs, for each change log one row will be added the table, Based on the ids we can know what Change logs are ran,

There are some flags like `runAlways`, `runOnChange`, these will help us to execute/ not execute.

you can refer to:

```
For understanding flags:
```

https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changeset.html

```
For understanding DATABASECHANGELOG Table:
```

https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangelog_table.html

Comment: Is there anyway I can set runAlways="false" or runOnChange="true" on all changesets when generating the changelogs? Or should this be done manually?

Comment: runOnChange to true. sometimes you have to delete the row in the table based on the situation